# How to use enum of Apollo-Server Graphql in resolver?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

## Environment

1. apollo-server
2. express
3. typescript
4. typeorm

## Type Definitions (typeDefs.ts)

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

const typeDefs = gql`

  enum Part {
    Hand, Arm, Waist, Bottom
  }

  type PartInfo {
    team: Int,
    tag: String,
    part: Part
  }

  ...

  type Query {
    ...
    hand(team: Int): PartInfo,
    ...
  }

`;
export default typeDefs;
```

## Resolvers (resolvers.ts)

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    ...
    hand: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const { team } = args;

      ...

      return {
        team,
        tag: "handTag",
        part: Part.hand
      }
    }
    ...
  },
};

export default resolvers;
```

## Problem

I want to use enum Part of `typeDefs.ts` at `resolvers.ts`

I tried

```
return {
    team,
    tag: "handTag",
    part: "Hand"
}
```

also, but dosent work.

How to use enum type which is defined in `typeDefs.ts` at `resolvers.ts` ?

check please!

Answer (score 1):

Besides Schema (typeDef.ts), you should also define your enum in resolver.

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    ...
    hand: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const { team } = args;

      ...

      return {
        team,
        tag: "handTag",
        part: Part.hand
      }
    }
    ...
  },
  Part: {
    Hand: Part.hand
  }
};

export default resolvers;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this as a constant(constant.ts) which can be used in schema and resolver as well. By doing so, you can change the values of the enum in one place in the future.

**Constants.ts**

```
 export const Parts = {
                    Hand: "hand",
                    Arm: "arm",
                    Waist: "waist",
                    Bottom: "bottom"
                  }
// values based on your requirements
```

**TypeDefs.ts**

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { Parts } from './constants'; // your relative file path


const typeDefs = gql`

  enum Part {
    ${Object.keys(Parts).join(" ")}
  }

  ...
`;
export default typeDefs;
```

Now the same constant can be used in your resolver function.

**Resolver.ts**

```
import { Parts } from './constants'; // your relative file path
    
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    ...
    hand: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const { team } = args;

      ...

      return {
        team,
        tag: "handTag",
        part: Parts.hand
      }
    }
    ...
  },
};

export default resolvers;
```